# Getting different y-axis range using plot/scatter on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I don't understand why I get different range for y axis when using `plt.plot` and `plt.scatter`. With the latter une range is only one decade and half of the data cannot be seen as it is out of the plot..
Can you explain me what happens ? Here are the code I use :

```
plt.yscale("log") ; 
plt.plot( df['Vgate'], df['Idrain'])
plt.grid(True)

plt.yscale("log") ; 
plt.scatter( df['Vgate'], df['Idrain'])
```

Using plot method [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLbLh.png)

Using scatter method [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CW5A.png)

NB : To clarify I just want the scatter method to automatically select the right y limit according to the data I plot

Comment: Hi @Sarah, welcome to SO! The `pyplot` lib auto fits graphs and markers within figures. To acchieve fixed axes ranges on different figures/plots, you'll have to do so manually by setting `ylim`, and equally for `x` . Checkout https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html

Comment: For a line plot the points need to be sorted. For example by sorting the dataframe on Vgate. Also, zero and negative values need to be avoided on the logscale  y axis.

Comment: @Wololo Maybe I have not been clear but these plots have been obtained with the same data, I would like the y-range to be adjusted automatically with scatter, as it is when I use plot

Comment: @Sarah , yes, I see that from your code. However, the auto fit/adjustment doesn't just evaluate the data. It also considers the markers' sizes, linewidth, etc. When using different plotting methods (plot vs scatter), the autofit will resolve differently. You could still get it "automatic" though:  What about setting `max_y = max(df['Idrain'])` and then for both plots, `plt.ylim(0, max_y*1.1)`. Another option could be to plot them both in the same figure? Finally, as JohanC suggests: try to sort the data before line-plotting.

Comment: @Wololo I have followed your advice, but 0 min limit doesnt work so I have replaced with
`


min_y = min(df['Idrain'].abs()) 
plt.ylim(min_y*0.5, max_y*3) 

`
I don't need the line plot, it was just to show the difference on y-range,
Thnaks a lot !